# Why does randomQuestion[0] === $("#question3") evaluate to false?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`

```
var questions = new Array($("#question1"), $("#question2"), $("#question3"))
var randomQuestion = questions.sort(() => .5 - Math.random());

console.log( randomQuestion[0] )
console.log(  $("#question3") )
if ( randomQuestion[0] === $("#question3") ){ alert("same")}
else { alert("unsame")} `
```

[image]

Why `if  randomQuestion[0] === $("#question3")` not work ?

All condition still show alert unsame.

Comment: maybe because the sort is randomic?

Comment: Use `(randomQuestion[0]).is($("#question3"))`

Comment: It's because you cannot compare jQuery objects directly. You need to compare properties of the objects - ideally an `id` if available

Comment: Why should it work? Even if `randomQuestion[0]` would contain the element with id `question3` you're comparing two distinct jQuery objects. This would only work with actual DOM nodes.

Comment: More info on [object comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Just like I told in the comment section, use `.is()` to check if the elements are same or not :)

```js
var questions = new Array($("#question1"), $("#question2"), $("#question3"))
var randomQuestion = questions.sort(() => .5 - Math.random());

console.log(randomQuestion[0])
console.log($("#question3"))

if ((randomQuestion[0]).is($("#question3"))) {
  alert("same")
} else {
  alert("unsame")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="question1">Question 1</div>
<div id="question2">Question 2</div>
<div id="question3">Question 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i know, you can't compare jquery objects, so try comparing DOM objects, like:

```
if (randomQuestion[0][0] === $('#question3')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(something)` creates a jQuery object. You are creating two identical jQuery objects, but object comparison doesn't care if objects are identical, only if they are the same object.

Compare DOM elements instead:

```
randomQuestion[0][0] === $("#question3")[0]
```

Or test the ID of the element:

```
randomQuestion[0]).is($("#question3")
```